# YouTube stream show subtitles below player

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

I am have been playing around with a lot of options. popcorn.js, mediaelement.js, jwplayer and I can not find a combination that works. I'm working on a learning website and I need to display the subtitles of the video below the player. I can get it to work all good when the video is hosted on the server and it has a file link. I was using MediaElement.js because all the videos I need are on YouTube so it needs to stream from there.

I have tried a few different combinations and popcorn was originally going to work. When I started playing with it I found their YouTube streaming no longer works. I've followed their examples but its a no-go. Also with popcorn I couldn't get to work with any other subtitle file other than TTML (even though they support the others) and I need one that can have html inside of it.

My latest endeavor got me using the script from here: http://www.storiesinflight.com/js_videosub/#code

This lets me use .srt which is good, but I can't get it to let me stream YouTube with any other JavaScript players so I'm back to where I started.

I have seen a post about going through one of the transcoding websites and using the .mp4 link, but I don't want to rely on a middleman. If that site shuts down then my site will also be screwed. I doubt YouTube is going anywhere anytime soon.

Comment: Why below player instead of within player? Just considering things like full-screen mode etc. Why can't the Youtube player show subtitles where available? I think you can improve your question by saying exactly how you access Youtube videos (because if you're embedding the official Youtube player, then this question makes no sense.. at least not to me)

Comment: I'm working on a section for my language learning website and I need people to be able to copy and paste the subtitles. Also need pop-up boxes to show when they hover over words.

Comment: @chris3spice I'm looking at trying to use, buy or build a similar tool. Did you ever come right?

Comment: I am making a bilingual website. I add youtube videos to my website. How can I show youtube subtitles in a separate place? Have you got the answer yet?

Answer (score 1):

There's a surefire way to do this and that's to  create your subtitles in notepad and then [upload them to youtube](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-Subtitles-to-YouTube-Videos)

Then Go to your Account Settings page in Youtube

- Select Playback from the left-hand menu
- Select/check 'Always show  captions'

You should Check Show automatic captions by speech recognition (when available) to enable automatic captions for videos that don't already have captions provided)

- Save! and you're done

No javascript required

Comment: That would work but I need HTML in the captions with pop-up boxes when hovering over words and stuff. Also I'm not using video's just from my channel but other people's as well.

Comment: @chris3spice oh well, worth a shot

Comment: @chris3spice i'd check this article out https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/07/adding-captions-and-subtitles-to-html5-video/